# Unable to access Minikube! message starting miniKube worries me: "Unable to resolve the Docker CLI context" "The system cannot find the path"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm facing error in Minikube

I was trying to start with `Minikube start` command

It gets following error

> Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context
> "default": context not found: open
> C:\Users\wmmth.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json:
> The system cannot find the path specified.

I tried to check `minikube status` and it shows the same error:

```
Unable to resolve the 
current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\Users\wmmth\.docker\contexts\meta\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\meta.json: The system cannot find the 
path specified.
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are getting below error  Identifying  what exactly went wrong with your Minikube Kubernetes cluster**

```
current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: open C:\\Users\\wmmth.docker\\contexts\\meta\\37a8eec1ce19687d132fe29051dca629d164e2c4958ba141d5f4133a33f0688f\\meta.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

**To fix the above error, take the actions listed below. We can solve your issue in four different ways. I'm hoping one of them can help you with your problem**.

**Option 1**: To change Docker's default context, use this command.

```
docker context use default
```

**Option 2**: If the last command  docker context use default. didn't work, please try this one:

```
 kubectl config set-context minikube
```

**Mostly first command helps to resolve your issue**

For more information refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/16788)

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? [What should I do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry I missed your chat and thanks for your response